# How to customize form web part to include multiple columns in search?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have edited my form web part to look like this.
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/75208ad105.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/75208ad105.jpg)

I am a newbie to moss. As i understand, form web part allows only 1 column to be mapped to my list at a time. I need to configure to it have multiple columns mapped to my list view. 
Do I need to change any javascript function or use sharepoint designer. I have spent a week trying to accomplish this. Stillon a dead end.
Please give some detailed information on how to accomplish this. Any guidance would be extremely helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating a multi-column search form in SharePoint v3 with SharePoint Designer](http://andyparkes.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/10/31/creating-a-multi-column-search-form-in-sharepoint-v3-with-sharepoint-designer/)